# error with selenium chromedriver in windows 10 x64

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with new project in Java on eclipse. I can't run it :(
I try change path for chromedriver, i restarted, and reinstall chromedriver.
What I can do more??
I haven't more idea. Help ! :(

> maj 04, 2017 10:41:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
>   SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Agnieszka\git\fcc-tests\driver\chromedriver" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=193, %1 nie jest prawidłową aplikacją systemu Win32)

```
`<i>` java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\Users\Agnieszka\...\...\...\chromedriver
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:142)
    at Utils.UtilsServers.openChrome(UtilsServers.java:23)
    at GeneralPages.Login.loginAsAgentSelenium(Login.java:16)
    at Agent.PlainPhoneTest.before(PlainPhoneTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utils.UtilsServers.driverClose(UtilsServers.java:47)
    at Agent.PlainPhoneTest.afterC(PlainPhoneTest.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) </i>
```

Comment: Maybe the ChromeDriver download was corrupted by a network error or something, so the chromedriver.exe is not correct. Can you try to  download ChromeDriver again from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: Also, can you check if antivirus or firewall is interrupting.

Comment: i tried download new chromedriver.. its the same.
Later i check antivirus ans firewall interrupting. The same ;(

Comment: why i have this file :
Unrooted Tests:
NameMyTest ??

Comment: can you paste the code snippet as well?

Comment: code from?? Im sorry..my english is not good

Comment: Code which you are trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the executable driver from:  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Then set the system property before creating the driver object.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path_to_chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It will be easy to debug, if you provide the code.